# Is there any Python equivalent to sort([op ;op+1])

Tags: python

As title, I have Matlab

```
op = [1 3 5]
[op ;op+1]
opf = sort([op ;op+1])
opf = [1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

and reading the doc, I've discovered that `;` could signify end of row. However I don't know if that's the case since it's in square brackets and in Matlab more often than not there are way too many ways of doing most of the things. Not that it's something bad to be honest, but it's at least a bit confusing for students like me.

To replicate in Python I did

```
opf = np.sort([op,op+1])
```

but `opf` shape is wrong. I get in fact `[[0 2 4] [1 3 5]]` which is (2,3). `opf` instead should be `[1 2 3 4 5 6]` and its shape accordingly (6,1)

Comment: Yes, you can probably sort lists in Python with the same criteria as you would in Matlab. Now, most [tag:python] users won't know [tag:matlab], so it would help if you could explain *in Python terms* how you want to sort what exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with `numpy` arrays, you cannot concatenate like you did on matlab.

The way to do it, is via `np.concatenate()`. Also, `np.concatenate()` takes in a tuple as its argument, so you must use double parenthesis (one to indicate the function, and the other for the tuple of the arrays you want to concatenate).

Your complete example would look something like this

```
import numpy as np


a = [1, 3, 5]

op = np.array(a)

result = np.sort(np.concatenate((op, op + 1)))

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in Python using regular lists:

```
import numpy as np

op = np.array([1, 3, 5])
opf = [[i, i+1] for i in op]
opf = [i for j in opf for i in j]
print(np.asarray(opf))
```

Returning:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

If your `op` array is unordered, you could do:

```
import numpy as np

op = np.array([1, 5, 3])

opf = [[i, i+1] for i in sorted(op)]
opf = [i for j in opf for i in j]

print(np.sort(np.asarray(opf)))
```

Again returning:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
np.reshape(6,1)
```

If you are using numpy you can reshape it yourself